# Magento2: How to call helper function in model?

Tags: magento2

I need to call helper function in model.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Abc\Mkt\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception as ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Abc\Mkt\Helper\ObjectManager;
class Callback extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
protected $objHelper;
    public function __construct(
          Abc\Mkt\Helper\ObjectManager $objHelper,
          \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        ){
           $this->objHelper = $objHelper;
           parent::__construct($context);
        }
public function afterSave()
{
$objectManager = $this->objHelper->getObjectManager();
$data='';
if(!$productobj){
throw new ValidatorException(__('Please Enter product Name. '));
}
}
```

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: ObjectManager is your helper class?

Comment: Yes @sukumar goral

Comment: Below answer should work. Try that.

Comment: But this is not working for me. I have tried it

Comment: Can you share your whole code? I mean other files as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
<?php

namespace Abc\Mkt\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception as ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;
use Abc\Mkt\Helper\ObjectManager;

class Callback extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    protected $objHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        ObjectManager $objHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->objHelper = $objHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    public function afterSave()
    {
        $objectManager = $this->objHelper->getObjectManager();
        $data='';
        if(!$productobj){
            throw new ValidatorException(__('Please Enter product Name. '));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps! Thanks